# Javascript onClick() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is my table where each row have 2 onClick event. When I click on each row it call the method's which I defined but Now you see that there are a check box to last column. I want if click on this check box then **no need to call this method in Javascript onClick**, is that possible ?

**note: here php while loop is running :**

```
echo "<tr onclick='getDetails($cdid), visited(this);'>";                
echo "<td class='' valign='top' align='left' width='20'>$companyName</td>";
echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$family_name</td>";
echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$given_name</td>";
echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$department</td>";
echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$title<input type='checkbox' name='add_to_project'/></td>";    
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

**Update:**

function getDetails(id) {

```
    try { 
        keepcontact = false;
        if($("#contentText").val() != "" && $("#contentText").val() != null)
        {
            var toCharNotes = $('#saveToChrNote').is(':checked');
            //AUTO save the charnotes if is checked without prompt
            if( toCharNotes == true ){
                var formData = new FormData($("#addNewNotes").parents('form')[0]);      
                    var cid=$(this).parents('form:first').find('#cdid').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'response.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        xhr: function() {
                            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                            return myXhr;
                        },
                        success: function(data){                      
                          getDetails2(id);  


                        }, 
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });
            } else {
                var saveNote = confirm("Save or clear Enter Note before proceeding ?");
                if (saveNote == true) {
                    var formData = new FormData($("#addNewNotes").parents('form')[0]);      
                    var cid=$(this).parents('form:first').find('#cdid').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'response.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        xhr: function() {
                            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                            return myXhr;
                        },
                        success: function(data){                      
                          getDetails2(id);  


                        }, 
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });

                } else {
                    keepcontact = true;
                    // do nothing.. :D
                    //getDetails2(id);
                }
            }
        } 
        else{
            getDetails2(id);
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        alert(err);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Stop propagation of checkbox click event, e.g: `$('[name=add_to_project]').on('click', function(e){e.stopPropagation();});`

Comment: @A.Wolff where i put this line of code ? In getDetails and visited method ?

Comment: You bind new click handler to all your specific checkboxes, or you could filter the event target in `getDetails()/visited()` methods. If you want more specific help, you need to provide complete minimalistic sample to replicate issue in question itself and maybe a jsFiddle too. Anyway, you shouldn't bind event using inline scripting

Comment: @A.Wolff I added getDetails() method to my question

Comment: @creativeartbd instead of using outdated discouraged inline JS take a look at event handlers, as A.Wolff has suggested.

Comment: @A.Wolff Simple and best Answer :)

Comment: @A.Wolff I see in first row this `stopPropagation()` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your function a bit

```
function visited(a)
{
 if(a.getAttribute("name")=="add_to_project") return;
// Rest of the code of your function

}
```

Put this line on the top of the function `visited`

```
if(a.getAttribute("name")=="add_to_project") return;
```

Modify the PHP a bit

```
echo "<tr onclick='getDetails($cdid, this), visited(this);'>";
```

And modify the `getDetails` function

```
function getDetails(a, b) 
{
if(b.getAttribute("name")=="add_to_project") return;
// Rest of the function

}
```

Comment: I added my getDetails() method to my questions. can you tell me where I exaclty put your code

Comment: 1. `a` always points to `<tr>`, so it never has `name` `"add_to_project"`. 2. `a` is not jQuery object, so `.attr()` causes an error. Please check code before posting it.

Comment: @void Im trying it but it's showing : Referenceerror : Id is inot defined

Answer (score 0):

You can stop event bubbling using `return false;` at the end of the `handler`.
Try this demo scenario,

***HTML :***

```
<table id="infoTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Click Here</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="innerCheckBox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

***jQuery :***

```
$("#infoTable tr").on("click", function(){
    alert("tr");
});

$("#innerCheckBox").on("click", function(){
    alert("checkbox");
    return false;
});
```

[***jsFIddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/rq5ktsk6/)